# Why does "consecutive" have a 'c' instead of a 'q'?

Tags: etymology, orthography, latin, digraphs

The etymology of the word shows it comes from the Latin *consequi*, to follow after, which is an origin of the word *sequential* as well. So why is *consecutive* not spelled *consequtive*, or why is *sequential* not spelled *secuential*?

Comment: Note that the perfect passive participle of the verb in Latin is *consecutus.*

Comment: If you're stating an etymology in the question, you should say where it is from. Etymonline, the OED, and Wiktionary answer this; the OED (which is the gold standard) doesn't mention *consequi* just Latin *consecūtīvus* and French *consecutif*. If you're using a substandard or outdated reference, it's useful to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## As Y is sometimes a vowel,
sometimes U is a consonant!

The main reason it’s spelled *consecutive* is because the that’s how that word has come down to us out of time immemorial from the [Eternal City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rome) herself, just as *consequence* has.

As for the reason why it cannot be spelled ❌*conse**qut**ive*, that’s because the [orthographic digraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_(orthography)#English) ‹qu› represented the /kw/ sound long ago in Latin, just as it does today in English. Notice the lack of a vowel in /kw/. We could not spell that word as you propose because that would then mean that the middle syllable would be /kwt/, something that violates [the phonotactic constraints of English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotactics#English_phonotactics).

Proto-Indo-European, the ancestor to both English and Latin alike, had [/kʷ/ as one of its basic phonemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_phonology#Consonants). How that was transmitted to its seemingly countless daughter tongues varies, and how these sounds came to be spelled once writing was invented would change even more exotically. For example, Old Icelandic used ‹kv› and wrote their word for queen as *kvæn*. We ourselves used to write this sound combination as ‹cw› in native English words, and so our own *queen* was originally written *cwen* in Old English.

In time, we swapped that around to something that looked more like Latin after the Norman Conquest infused our writing and our tongue with the habits of Norman French during Middle English. But this took a long to settle. The OED has this to say within its much longer etymology section for the letter Q: <sup>([paywalled link](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/q_n?tab=meaning_and_use#etymology))</sup>

> The consonant cluster /kw/ occurs frequently in Old English words
> of Germanic descent. In early writings in Old English (for
> example in the earliest glosses and occasionally in the Rushworth
> gospels) it is sometimes represented by *qu* (as an adoption from
> Latin orthography), but the normal representation in Old English
> orthography is *cw* (i.e. with the Old English letter wynn (see W
> n.); in early use also *cu*, occasionally *cuu*).
>
> After the Norman Conquest, the spelling qu for /kw/ again begins
> to be found, although at first somewhat sporadically. (In some
> manuscripts it is particularly frequent in words of French
> origin, but this is not invariably the case.) By the end of the
> 13th cent. *qu* (with *u* frequently indicated by an
> abbreviation) is the usual spelling (also, although extremely
> rare before 1300, *qv* or *qw*), and *cw* ceases to be found
> (although *ku* and *kw* are found in some manuscripts of the 14th
> and 15th centuries).

I have omitted the part of the OED discussion where it mentions how in later French, the /kw/ sound of written ‹qu› became simplified to just /k/ alone. This explains words more recently imported into English from French, including ones like *quiche* /kiʃ/, *unique* /juˈnik/, and *opaque* /oˈpek/. (This is because French spelling is conservative: they do not update their orthography when the sounds it represents change as other Romance languages sometimes do. They don’t respell *cuisine* to ❌*quisine* either. :)

In any case, written ‹qu› in English is only ever the consonant cluster /kw/, not a consonant and then a vowel like /ku/ — which among other things is why you cannot spell the word pronounced /kjut/ as *qute*. Nobody would understand you. You can only have written ‹q› without a vowel following it in exotic loanwords from other tongues where it different represented a different consonant than /k/ as it does in English, such as *Qatar* or *Qatari*. See [Wikipedia’s list of exceptions to this rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_containing_Q_not_followed_by_U).

Comment: "written ‹qu› in English is only ever the consonant cluster /kw/" well of course sometimes it's just /k/ (plaque, uniquely, chequing etc) but you already knew that...

Comment: (And let's not forget "barbeque"!)

Comment: @psmears Yes, that's right: those are all from French, where the it's just /k/, them having dropped the /w/ that used to represent. I had omitted that from my quote taken the more lengthy discussion from the OED.  My main point is that it can't represent /ku/, and that it cannot be its own syllable as his **consequtive*  would propose. That's just now how we use that letter in our language.

Comment: I'm aware of that - I'm suggesting you could improve the answer by softening the assertion "... _only ever_ the consonant cluster /kw/", perhaps by adding something like "(or occasionally /k/)".

Comment: "You can only have written ‹q› without a vowel following it in exotic loanwords from other tongues ... such as Qatar or Qatari": last I checked, ‹a› is a vowel.  Did you mean "‹q› without ‹u› following it"?

Comment: @phoog When you write *quick*, the vowel following the digraph is I. The entire QU means /kw/ and there is no vowel there.

Comment: That is true, but doesn't contradict what @phoog said: the "Q" in "Qatari" **is** followed by a vowel. Perhaps "buqsha",  "miqrah" or "waqf" (from the list you link) would make your point better? Or did you mean "not followed by 'u'" in place of "not followed by a vowel", as phoog suggests?

Answer (score 2):

**Consecutive** arrived in English from France in the late 16th to early 17th century as the anglicization of the French "Consecutif"

OED

> **1.Following continuously; following each its predecessor in uninterrupted succession.**
>
> 1611 *Consecutif*, consecutiue, or consequent; next or immediately succeeding. *R. Cotgrave, Dictionarie of French & English Tongues*

We need look no further for a reason for the spelling.

It has remained remarkably constant in its spelling since then.

However, the OED records a single instance of the "qu" in a now obsolete meaning

> **3.a.Following as a consequence or effect; consequent (to).** Obsolete.
>
> 1647 Accused of accidentall and consequutive Blasphemy and Idolatry.
> *Bishop J. Taylor, Θεολογία Ἐκλεκτική xx. 261*

I could speculate that the good Bishop was (a) much given to the Classics (b) not too hot on etymology.

Comment: Notice that even Bishop Taylor needed a vowel in the penultimate syllable  of his curiosity “*consequ**u**tive*”, for without one it would stop being a syllable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that the answers don't really capture the real reason, which is that it's modeled after the Latin spelling. It would *never* have been a -qu- in English, because it comes from the past participle, [*consecutus*](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic+letter%3DC%3Aentry+group%3D92%3Aentry%3Dconsequor), codified with this spelling in Classical Latin and transmitted through the Medieval ages as such. Like many other past participles in Latin, it was given an adjectival ending *-ivus, -a, -um*, yielding *consecutivus (consecutiva, consecutivum*, depending on the gender of the noun). It was transmitted to French as *consecutif*, but English speakers reverted to the more Latin spelling over the course of time.

Meanwhile, words like *consequential* derive from the present participle, *consquens*, stem *consequent-*.

That the stem changed is not unusual. You see a radical change of spelling in most Latin verbs when moving from the present to the past tenses. Sometimes it's as simple as adding a -t- to the thematic root (to love: *ama-re*, loved: *ama-tum*), but with 3rd conjugation verbs, they didn't have a thematic vowel with them, so the -t- gets added to a vowel-less stem. For example, with the verb *dico* (I speak), *dicere* (to speak), *dixi* (I spoke), *dictum* (having been spoken, uttered), the -t- is placed right on the stem *dic-*. That's what's happening with *consequor*.

I should also note that the shift from q to c happened because Roman spelling conventions changed. Etruscan and early Roman spelling had 3 letters for the same sound, depending on the succeeding vowel:  + e/i = ce/ci,  + a = ka,  + u/o = qu/qo.<sup>1</sup> This was largely abandoned and K was dropped with a couple archaic exceptions.

But the Romans themselves changed their spelling (at multiple times, at multiple instigations by various people). Even with *consecutus*, you will find next to it an alternate spelling *consequutus*, likely pronounced the same as *consecutus* (if Allen is to be believed).<sup>2</sup>

What we inherited in English is a Late Classical system laid on top of Latin as it evolved into French, with the two not always playing nicely (which explains why it's [*color*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/color) in American English, a learned re-spelling hearkening back to the original Latin spelling, and *colour* in British English, which is more closely aligned with the French *couleur*).

Why Latin had c- at all here is largely historical accident, and irrelevant to why it's spelled that way in English. The chief reason is that it was spelled that way in Latin.

<sup>1</sup> Penney 2011. "Archaic and Old Latin," in Clackson ed. *Companion to the Latin Language*, pp. 220-235. Wiley-Blackwell.

<sup>2</sup> Allen 1978. *Vox Latina*, p. 20. 2nd ed. Cambridge.